# Precedence of multiple styles for the same target type?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

If there are multiple styles like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
...
```

that are merged in from resource dictionaries that target the same type of control, which should have precedence, is it the first style encountered or last one?

Where can I find the rules that govern such things?

Comment: You can't merge them in to one dictionary because they have same key.

Comment: @Hamlet even if I don't x:name the styles?

Comment: @Chanakya: Elements in ResourceDictionaries have Keys, not Names. Read my answer below, it explains why it is not possible. (There is an implicit key). And if you think about it, how would .NET know which of the two styles to use? Imagine they are the identical save for one having a Red color and the other a Blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styles are applied from the ResourceDictionary closest to the control in question. An example:

```
 <Window>
    <Window.Resource>
        <Style 1/>
    <Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style 2/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the above example, Style 2 will be applied to the TextBox. Should you wish to cascade the styles (apply both styles to the TextBox), you can set `BasedOn` on Style2 to point to Style1 using `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"`. Please check the syntax, I don't have VS here.

As you can see, the type becomes the `Key`. Since it is not permissible to have two elements with the same key in a single `ResourceDictionary`, you cannot merge two ResourceDictionaries with overlapping styles. It should be possible to design around such a requirement, remembering that a ResourceDictionary can reference another use. Again, you use `BasedOn`.

Comment: Thankyou, this answers my original point about rules, and although I can't accept both answers, Hamlet's answer did help understanding when in same resource dictionary and the point about keys.

Comment: Syntax checks out. I didn't realise that you could use BasedOn without referring to a Style by key. Very useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer for your comment and for question at all. `Name, x:Name` doesn't play on the scene in this case. Each resource in the dictionary must have the `Key`. For targeted styles WPF infrastructure generates the `Key`, so, the styles with the same target type will have same key, thus you can't use more than one targeted style for each type in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It will throw an exception. This is what I tried to test this:

I wrote a simple `ResourceDictionary` with 2 styles, with same `TargetType` but without `x:Key` (not `x:Name`).

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
</Style>
```

Rebuilt the project and it complied successfully. Now which will get applied?

Well, when I ran it, it threw a big exception when loading the styles. So in short, it doesn't work.