# General WPF Rendering Rules (Multiple styles on same target type)

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

Relating on this question ([Multiple styles on same target type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413801/multiple-styles-on-same-target-type)) i have another point concerning the general wpf styling rules.

As mentioned in one of the answers above, wpf applies the closest style definition to the control when no x:key is specified. (also applies to styles with the same key; given the fact that we have the same key here: the control type)

My question:
What if we have two same-named styles in different resource dictionaries that are both equal close and accessible to the control?

Compared to CSS you have two definitions for i.e. an a-element. In CSS same style properties are getting overriden by the last definition while different properties are merged into one logical style definition.

Does WPF behave the same or does it prefer one whole style-resource with all its properties while avoiding the other one completely?

And if the latter how does it decide to apply one or the other.

### Update

#### dict1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SomeValue1" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="SomeValue2" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="SomeValue3" />
 </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

#### dict2.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SomeValue4" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SomeValue5" />
 </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

#### SomeView.xaml:

```
...
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 <ResourceDictionary Source="path/dict1.xaml" />
 <ResourceDictionary Source="path/dict2.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Grid>
 <Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="SomeValue6" />
  </Style>
 </Grid.Resources>

 <Button /><!--THIS IS THE CONTROL THAT MATTERS-->
</Grid>
...
```

I think for FontSize its simple, it applies SomeValue6 because its the closest style definition. But what about BorderBrush. Both Dictionaries are equally close to the Button and are both accessible.

And What about Background and Foreground? Does it merge both style definitions to something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="SomeValue4" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="SomeValue2" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="SomeValue5" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="SomeValue6" />
 </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Of course the chaos is much bigger when you include cross-assembly dictionaries, that depend on each other and you are seeking where the actual style comes from.

This code example isn't working because of the merged dictionary and its hard to isolate the exact behavior because my actual application is really chaotic like I described.

So I want to know the official rules intended by Microsoft that should be basic for every developer. But I didnt find anything in the docs.

Comment: _"What if we have two same-named styles in different resource dictionaries that are both equal close and accessible to the control"_ -- it's not really clear what you mean by "equal close and accessible". Of course, if you were to write [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, then you could probably just run the code and see what it does.

Comment: now I provided a code example. Sorry i'm german i think it should be "equally close to the control and both accessible"

Comment: Please read the link I offered, in which it is explain what a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example is, and how and why to provide one. As far as the phrase "equal[ly] close to the control and [both] accessible", your revised version doesn't add anything to my comprehension. It's not a matter of the grammar; it's a matter of the non-technical language and too-brief statement. The word "close" in particular has no well-defined technical meaning here, and while "accessible" does, it's not clear it's being used in the well-defined way (e.g. as in `public` vs `private` access).

Comment: OK! I reread your link and it didn't add anyting to my comprehension as well.

As you noticed i don't have a special problem rather than a simple question.

I also prefer a well-defined language. In this context the word "close" is well-defined, if you read the other stackoverflow-question linked at the top of my question. It means that that style is applied that appears next in the usual wpf-order as explained [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/using-styles/).

As i explained i am not able to extract a complete, minimal working example from my project in an acceptable timeframe.

Comment: please ask me at which concrete point my non-technical language limits your comprehension. Until now you simply criticised my question-style and my language. Sure its important for stackoverflow to discipline new members but i really try to follow the board rules. I try to look at my question from your perspective and it really should be possible to answer it.